# How to do a location wise pixel correspondence between two different layers?

Tags: qgis, dem, concatenation

I have two separate rasters, an RGB orthophoto and a grayscale DEM of the same location. I need to run an object detection algorithm on the RGB orthophoto and then make the bounding box I receive correspond to the same location on the DEM as well to calculate the heights.

I am very new to GIS and hence don't have the required amount of know-how to work with QGIS, so I loaded both the rasters in as NumPy arrays. The problem is that both arrays have different dimensions despite being the same photograph, so I cannot do a coordinate correspondence. Is there a way to solve this using Python or QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Seems like you have several different problems going on here. 1. Object detect. 2. projecting image coordinate space to geographic projection  3. Create a polygon from the projected coordinates 4. given a polygon and DEM sample elevations.  For 2, 3, 4  I would be surprised if have not already been asked and answered on this stack. 1) I would suggest opencv.  I also suggest decomposing your question into smaller questions.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor I have figured out 1, my problem is only 2, 3, 4 because I do not have much experience with GIS software and mostly deal with computer vision problems. I tried searching on here but couldn't find the exact terminology to generate the search string because I am not familiar with the lingo